# Open With... Tilix

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I need a more robust Terminal emulator, hence Tilix. However, I miss the option to open the terminal in the chosen directory under pantheon-files. Is it possible to add a contractor so to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the [script](https://github.com/theJaxon/elementaryOS/blob/master/open-in-tilix.desktop) in 'usr/share/applications', now it should be listed in 'open in > Other Application..' in the context menu, if not then restart and check if it appears, here's a screenshot after placing the script in the correct location.

[image: tilix appearing in elementary os context menu]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the sub menu 'open in' in pantheon on a directory and choose 'terminal'?

[image]

Comment: Tilix is not showing up in the open as list.

Comment: My miss, did not read correctly. You can try to add a contractor see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92494/how-to-add-open-folder-as-root-in-elementary-os-file-manager-context-menu#92508).